# ionic no muestra contenido

Tags: ionic, ionic4

Hola recientemente comencé a aprender `JavaScript`, junto con `ionic`, les comento mi problema: al poner código en el constructor no me muestra contenido, mejor dicho deja de mostrar el contenido. Trataba de realizar una `app` tipo linterna y me encuentro con este inconveniente que me deja la pantalla en blanco al colocar `constructor( public flash : Flashlight)` en el constructor.

este es mi archivo `home.page.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Flashlight } from '@ionic-native/flashlight/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor( public flash : Flashlight){

  }

  switchFlash(evento){
    let power = evento.target.checked;

    if (power) {
      this.flash.switchOn();
    } else {
      this.flash.switchOff();
    }
  }

}
```

Y este el de `home.page.html`:

```
    <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
        Ionic Blank
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>


  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="switchFlash($event)"/>
    <div>
      <span class="on">On</span>
      <span class="off">Off</span>
    </div>  
    <i></i>
  </label>

  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate si registraste tu plugin en app.module.ts pues es el error común al instalar un plugin. Si no lo registras donde de comenté es el principal causante de pantallazo blanco.